# Matlab - How to sum 1 to 1E10 serie of 1/x optimaly (in a few minutes) - matlab slows down

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with matlab. I need to sum math serie 1/x from 1 to 1E10. I have some code in Matlab which contains loop - first loop step is ok very fast), but on second step in loop it slows down and Matlab is almost freezed, so I cannot calculate this in appropriate time.

Can you help me with this?

For smaller range it works OK (for example 1E06), but I need to calculate for the whole range. I have tried to separate to smaller range, but there is still loop and matlab is very slowed.

It looks like a problem with matlab and for loop, which slows down. After first loop step the RAM is full but for the second loop step the RAM is still full so it slows down. I don´t know why the Matlab does not free the RAM.

Thank you for any help!

Vladimir

Comment: How does that use a lot of RAM? Could you show us the code you're using?

Comment: Definitely, post your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to obtain the 1e10-th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). In the Symbolic Toolbox there is a function for that, called [`harmonic`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/harmonic.html), and it's very fast:

```
>> format long %// to see more decimals
>> n = 1e10;
>> harmonic(n)
ans =
  23.603066594891992
```

The reason why it's so fast is that the `harmonic` function exploits the [relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Applications) between harmonic numbers, the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function):

[image] 
where "psi" is the digamma function, *H*<sub>*n*</sub> is the *n*-th harmonic number, and "gamma" is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. So you could also use

```
>> n = 1e10;
>> vpa(psi(n+1) + eulergamma)
ans =
    23.603066594891987434787570068504
```

If you don't have the Symbolic Toolbox, you can still do:

```
>> g = 0.5772156649015328606065120900824; %// Euler-Mascheroni constant
>> n = 1e10;
>> psi(n+1) + g
ans =
  23.603066594891988
```

Comment: Nice answer! I would also add this link to Matlab documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/harmonic.html?nocookie=true&s_tid=gn_loc_drop

Comment: this look great - unfortunately I don´t have Symbolic toolbox, so my matlab does not know harmonic as well as eulergamma. My Matlab is 2010b. I have tried whole thing in loop with sum of scalar and in opposite with sum in vectors. But the result is different (on place E-13)- between these workflows and the version with sum values in vector looks better - in comparison with results from Wolfram Alpha, but there is the problem with slow matlab in loop with vector. So your result is ok - 23.6030665948919, but mine is 23.6030665948912 (the last digists are different)

Comment: Summing 1e10 elements (even in vectorized chunks)  has to be slow

Comment: my friend told me, that he make it in a 6 minutes approx, but he cannot help me how, and my solution takes hours. I will edit the code for posting

Comment: If you don't have the Symbolic Toolbox, you only need to define the constant manually. See edit