# Smallest integer greater than or equal to harmonic series of input

Tags: matlab, function, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm working on the following problem:

[image]

I realize my code is a bit off, but I want to create a for loop that will determine whether or not the integer x (the input value) is at least less than or equal to the sum of a harmonic series.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 function n =one_per_n(x)
 if x > 10000
     n = -1;
 end
 total = 0;
 i = 0;
 for i = 1:10000
      if x >= total
          n = ceil(total);
      else
          total = (1/i) + total;


  end


  end
```

I've added my attempt at a while loop. I realize it's wrong, but any help would  be appreciated.

```
 function n =one_per_n(x)
 if x > 10000
     n = -1;
 end
 total = 0;
 i = 0;
 for i = 1:10000
      while total <= x
          total = (1/i) + total;
  end
  end
```

n = total;

Comment: Use `break` to exit the loop once you found `n` (in the `if` statement)

Comment: Also, there's no need to increment `i` via `i = i + 1;`. This is already done by the `for` loop itself

Comment: Read this: [Loop Control Statements](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html)

Comment: I understand the concepts, I'm just having a bit of difficulty putting it all together. I need to break when the total of the for loop exceeds the input value.

Comment: Indeed. Break after `n = ceil(total);`. Also, the first check (`if x > 10000`) is irrelevant.

Comment: Please reread the explanation in the link above. It will really help clear things up for you.

Comment: The answer I put in uses the while loop correctly.

Comment: You could speed up your code using 1) [Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (instead of linear search) search; and 2) Computing the harmonic numbers [more efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141084/matlab-how-to-sum-1-to-1e10-serie-of-1-x-optimaly-in-a-few-minutes-matlab)

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to use some loops:

```
function n = one_per_n(x)
lim   = min(10000,exp(x));
value = cumsum(1./(1:lim));
n     = find(value >= x,1); 
if isempty(n)
    n = -1;
end
```

Comment: Good but actually the solution is not so efficient considering your memory. The `lim` must be on `x` the length of `a` will be way larger. You could use `value = cumsum(1 ./ (1 : lim));`

Answer (score 0):

A while loop is a better option in this case I think

```
function [total, n] = one_per_n(x)
% This is a good initial check, good work
if x > 10000
    n = -1;
    return;
end

% Initialize the variables
total = 0;
n = 0;

% While not finished
while (total < x)
    % Number of terms
    n = n + 1;
    total = total + 1/n;
end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to post my updated code with a while loop. It's wrong, but if anyone can point out my mistake I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You should use a `return` after `if`.